# Access denied when creating a virtual directory via Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, windows-server-2008, web-deployment-project

I’m trying to use a (VS 2008) Web Deployment project in a TFS solution to deploy the web site to the (TFS 2008) build server to run web based unit tests. 
For some reason, that I can't yet figure out, it is failing to create the virtual directory:

Using "CreateVirtualDirectory" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.Tasks.dll".
Task "CreateVirtualDirectory"
  Initializing IIS Web Server...
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(667,5): error : Access is denied.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(667,5): error : 
  Failed to create virtual directory 'abc'.
Done executing task "CreateVirtualDirectory" -- FAILED.

The TFSService user certainly is in the Administrators group on the TFS Build machine (which is running Windows Server 2008). I don’t know what else could be wrong. I’ve checked the event log an there’s no clues there. I am able to manually create the virtual directory on that machine through the IIS console with no problem.

Any ideas what could be the problem or suggestions for how to diagnose this further?

Answer (score 1):

it has got to be permissions...did you try putting the TFSService in the same Groups you are in?

Answer (score 1):

Is the TFS account running under the same privileges as the account that you use to connect to IIS?  Do as Craig suggested and move the TFS account into the groups that you participate in.

Answer (score 0):

You're sure that the build is running under the TFSService id and not under another id set up just for builds, and which may not be in the administrator's group?  I haven't done more than just play with automated builds since I do mostly solo development, but I recall setting up a separate build id when I was looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this occur when the IIS server wasn't running on the default port. I'd recommend checking IIS to see if it's running on port 80 as a step to diagnose your issue further.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to get deployment working by calling the _CopyWebApplication build target of the web application from my TFS build script (after manually creating the IIS virtual directory).
I had to add an additional target though to get linked files in the project to be copied also as the built in _CopyWebApplication target doesn't include those.